# How to unwind all threads on panic?

Tags: multithreading, rust, panic

What's the least terrible way to implement 'unwind all threads on panic'? I would like to have every thread (attempt to) gracefully die on panics and SIGINTs (and notice SIGKILLs?).

It doesn't appear there is a Rust way to interrupt threads, so I'm thinking that I would implement a trait akin to `runOneStep` and have my threads check a boolean or look at libc interrupt handling.

I've seen [How can I cause a panic on a thread to immediately end the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988775), which is basically the hacky way of setting `panic=abort`.
I've also seen [Thread::cancel() support](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/thread-cancel-support/3056).

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on your goal? Since you've already read the linked Internals forum post, you understand why something like `Thread::cancel` would be a bad idea. What's wrong with just terminating the program?

Comment: I have cleanup on some threads that I would like to be very confident is run. Having a separate program watch for this one's health would work, but I feel that adds more complexity.

This kind of thing in Java would be provided by a ShutDownHook, but that is some runtime magic.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do anything graceful on a SIGKILL.  That's what SIGKILL means.  There's a less austere kill, I think it's called ABORT. (I'm an old-schooler, and I refer to them by their numbers: kill is 9, abort was, I think, 15.)

Comment: If only there was some resource you could reference to be sure what the signal names and numbers were... ^_^ If OP decides to switch to a different signal, what would be the solution?

Comment: OP asks: *gracefully die **on panics** and sigkills* (emphasis mine); what solutions exist for this case?