# How to handle unrecoverable errors in a thread in Gtk-rs?

Tags: multithreading, rust, gtk, gtk-rs

I'm writing a Gtk-rs application. I have a background thread sending events to the main Gtk thread through a MPSC channel.
What should I do with unrecoverable errors inside this background thread?

I don't want to handle them ([To panic! or Not to panic!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-03-to-panic-or-not-to-panic.html)).

Currently, the thread will panic, but the main application won't stop. I'd like the whole application to crash with the error.

```rust
let (sender, receiver) = glib::MainContext::channel(glib::PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

// Spawn the thread and move the sender in there
thread::spawn(move || {
    loop {
        let msg = do_work().unwrap();
        sender.send(msg).unwrap();
    }
});
receiver.attach(None, move |msg| {
    ...
    glib::Continue(true)
});
```

- I don't want to send a Result through the channel because it wouldn't work for panics in called functions.
- Joining the thread would solve the problem, but I don't think I can do it with Gtk-rs since it is blocking.

This question is similar to [How can I cause a panic on a thread to immediately end the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35988775/4074995), but I wonder there is a better solution for Gtk-rs.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the panic handler with [`set_hook`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.set_hook.html) would solve the problem.

```rust
fn change_panic_behaviour() {                
    let hook = std::panic::take_hook();
    std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(move |error| {
        hook(error);
        std::process::exit(1);
    }));
}
```