# How to make tokio test fail if thread panicked?

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, rust, mocking, rust-tokio

I have a struct with implementation that uses automock from [mockall](https://crates.io/crates/mockall) crate:

```
pub struct MyStruct {...}

#[cfg_attr(test, automock)] 
impl MyStruct {
...
    pub async fn my_struct_function() {...}
...
}
```

I need to test that `my_struct_function` is called exactly once by another async method:

**Update**: I expressed the problem in a poor manner. If `other_async_method` calls `my_struct_function` it's fine, they both run in the same task. But in my case `other_async_method` spawns a new task and `my_struct_function` is called in this new task. This is why the main task of the test doesn't "see" the panic and succeeds.

```
#[tokio::test]
async fn my_test() {
...
    let mut my_struct_mock = MockMyStruct::default();
    my_struct_mock.
        .expect_my_struct_function()
        .times(1)
        .returning(...);

    let result: Result<...> = OtherStruct::init_method(..., my_struct_mock, ...)
        .other_async_method()  // updated: spawns a new task that calls MockMyStruct::my_struct_function
        .await;
...
}
```

At the moment if I change the `times(1)` method to some other value N the test is still succesfull, because the code panics in a tokio thread, and not the main test thread.
I can verify it by running the test with `nocapture` option:

```
$ cargo test my_test -- --nocapture

thread '...tests::test_my_test' panicked at 'MockMyStruct::my_struct_function: Expectation(<anything>) called 1 time(s) which is fewer than expected N'
```

How can I make the test fail when there is a discrepancy between the expected and the actual number of times the function is called?

I am a novice to Rust and wasn't able to find a solution sound by searching online. But I expect that there is a solution at the library level (mockall of tokio test) and not a "hack".

Comment: Do you mean the code panics in a task spawned by `tokio::spawn()`? If you can't change the code creating the task to propagate the error, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue in the mockall GitHub repository: https://github.com/asomers/mockall/issues/461

The owner asomers suggested to use the [checkpoint](https://docs.rs/mockall/latest/mockall/#checkpoints) method and it solved my problem:

> you can use mockedObject.checkpoint() to verify that all of its
> expectations have been satisfied prior to dropping the object.

```
#[tokio::test]
async fn my_test() {
...
    let mut my_struct_mock = MockMyStruct::default();
    my_struct_mock.
        .expect_my_struct_function()
        .times(1)
        .returning(...);

    let result: Result<...> = OtherStruct::init_method(..., my_struct_mock, ...)
        .other_async_method()  // updated: spawns a new task that calls MockMyStruct::my_struct_function
        .await;

    my_struct_mock.checkpoint();
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using tokio with the [`tokio_unstable`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/#unstable-features) feature enabled, you can use the [`Builder::unhandled_panic`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.unhandled_panic) method to build a tokio runtime that panics when a task panics:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use tokio::runtime::{self, UnhandledPanic};

    #[test]
    #[should_panic]
    fn test() {
        let rt = runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
            .unhandled_panic(UnhandledPanic::ShutdownRuntime)
            .build()
            .unwrap();

        let task1 = rt.spawn(async { panic!("boom"); });

        rt.block_on(async {
            task1.await.ok();
        });
    }
}
```

When I run `cargo test -- --nocapture` I get the following output:

```
running 1 test
thread 'tests::test' panicked at 'boom', src/main.rs:18:38
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread 'tests::test' panicked at 'a spawned task panicked and the runtime is configured to shut down on unhandled panic', src/main.rs:20:12
test tests::test - should panic ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

Comment: Thanks, I can also use `panic::set_hook` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36031130/21257731) to exit from the test and make it fail. But my hope was that there is some easier, built in the test crates, way to do it, instead of having to enable tokio unstable or creating custom panic hooks...